# Jenkins Websphere deploy Wsadmin error

Tags: java, jenkins, websphere

I have jenkins and websphere setup on a windowsxp environment. whenever i try to run the build step to invoke WAS deployer plugin to deploy application.ear through wsadmin I get this following error.

```
Building in workspace C:\.jenkins\jobs\websphereantdeploy\workspace
Using user admin defined at the build step level
$ C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\wsadmin.bat -conntype SOAP -host localhost -port 9080 -user admin -password ******** -lang jacl -f c:/workspace/ex5.jacl C:/workspace/revision_document/build/ant/riversource.ear karanvmxpNode01
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'IBM WebSphere Application Server 6.x/7.x' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea how i can change the path for wsadmin in jenkins to specify PROGRA~1 instead of program files cauz i think that might be the issue here. please do correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve your problem you need to add quotes in your command.

```
"<WAS_PATH>" -conntype SOAP -host localhost
```

Also, I wouldn't recommend to install `WAS` into `Program Files` directory or into directory with spaces in it's name.